# Сумму нашел, а кол-во не получается. Как сделать?

Tags: javascript, функции

Напишите функцию `sumOfPositive`, которая принимает массив `arr` как аргумент и возвращает кол-во положительных элементов этого массива.

Функция `sumOfPositive ([1, 2, -3, 4])` должна возвратить 3;
Функция `sumOfPositive ([-2, -4])` должна возвратить 0;
Функция `sumOfPositive ([])` должна возвратить;

```js
function sumOfPositive(arr) {
  let s = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] > 0) {
      s += arr[i];
    }
  }
  return s
}
console.log(sumOfPositive([1, 2, -3, 4]));
console.log(sumOfPositive([-2, -4]));
console.log(sumOfPositive([]));
```

Comment: `s += arr[i];` замените на `s++;`

Answer (score 4):

```
function getPositiveCount(arr) {
  return arr.filter(el => el > 0).length
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Примерно то же, что у вас, но с использованием reduce

```js
function sumOfPositive (array) {
  return array.reduce( (sum, number) => {
    return number > 0 ? ++sum : sum;
  }, 0);
}

console.log( sumOfPositive([1, 2, -3, 4]) );
console.log( sumOfPositive([-2, -4]) );
console.log( sumOfPositive([]) );
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
function sumOfPositive(arr){
let s = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] > 0){
    s++ // если условие верно то просто +1 в счетчик s можно записать как s = s + 1
  }
  }
  return s
}
console.log(sumOfPositive([1, 2, -3, 4]));
console.log(sumOfPositive([-2, -4]));
console.log(sumOfPositive([]));
```